# How to convert html with lots of svg charts into a pdf?

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I have a dashboard with lots of svg charts. I need to give a feature to export this entire html as a pdf.

I looked into few tools like phantomjs and htmltocanvas etc. But I am unable to convert svg into pdf or even images.

I thought, may be using htmltocanvas I'll first convert html into png and then convert png into pdf using phantomjs.

htmltocanvas converts rest of the html page into png but not the svg charts.

Is there any better way or tools to do this?

Below is the code to convert html to image.

```
html2canvas($(".content"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                window.location.href = img;

            }
        });
```

and one of the SVG chart is as follows.

```
<svg width="330" height="320" style="overflow: hidden;"><defs><clipPath id="c3-1462852070590-clip"><rect width="330" height="316"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="c3-1462852070590-clip-xaxis"><rect x="-31" y="-20" width="392" height="20"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="c3-1462852070590-clip-yaxis"><rect x="-29" y="-4" width="20" height="340"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="c3-1462852070590-clip-grid"><rect width="330" height="316"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="c3-1462852070590-clip-subchart"><rect width="330"></rect></clipPath></defs><g transform="translate(0.5,4.5)"><text class="c3-text c3-empty" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" x="165" y="158" style="opacity: 0;"></text><rect class="c3-zoom-rect" width="330" height="316" style="opacity: 0;"></rect><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip)" class="c3-regions" style="visibility: hidden;"></g><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-grid)" class="c3-grid" style="visibility: hidden;"><g class="c3-xgrid-focus"><line class="c3-xgrid-focus" x1="-10" x2="-10" y1="0" y2="316" style="visibility: hidden;"></line></g></g><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip)" class="c3-chart"><g class="c3-event-rects c3-event-rects-single" style="fill-opacity: 0;"><rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-0" x="0" y="0" width="330" height="316"></rect></g><g class="c3-chart-bars"><g class="c3-chart-bar c3-target c3-target-FS1" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS1 c3-bars c3-bars-FS1" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-bar c3-target c3-target-FS2" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS2 c3-bars c3-bars-FS2" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-bar c3-target c3-target-Renewal" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Renewal c3-bars c3-bars-Renewal" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-bar c3-target c3-target-Tele-sales" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Tele-sales c3-bars c3-bars-Tele-sales" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g></g><g class="c3-chart-lines"><g class="c3-chart-line c3-target c3-target-FS1" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS1 c3-lines c3-lines-FS1"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS1 c3-areas c3-areas-FS1"></g><g class=" c3-selected-circles c3-selected-circles-FS1"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS1 c3-circles c3-circles-FS1" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-line c3-target c3-target-FS2" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS2 c3-lines c3-lines-FS2"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS2 c3-areas c3-areas-FS2"></g><g class=" c3-selected-circles c3-selected-circles-FS2"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS2 c3-circles c3-circles-FS2" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-line c3-target c3-target-Renewal" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Renewal c3-lines c3-lines-Renewal"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Renewal c3-areas c3-areas-Renewal"></g><g class=" c3-selected-circles c3-selected-circles-Renewal"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Renewal c3-circles c3-circles-Renewal" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-line c3-target c3-target-Tele-sales" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Tele-sales c3-lines c3-lines-Tele-sales"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Tele-sales c3-areas c3-areas-Tele-sales"></g><g class=" c3-selected-circles c3-selected-circles-Tele-sales"></g><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Tele-sales c3-circles c3-circles-Tele-sales" style="cursor: pointer;"></g></g></g><g class="c3-chart-arcs" transform="translate(122.984375,158)"><text class="c3-chart-arcs-title" style="text-anchor: middle; opacity: 0;"></text><g class="c3-chart-arc c3-target c3-target-FS1"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS1 c3-arcs c3-arcs-FS1"><path class=" c3-shape c3-shape c3-arc c3-arc-FS1" transform="" d="M7.154090006472169e-15,-116.83515625A116.83515625,116.83515625 0 1,1 -107.89143050974987,44.831829747643916L0,0Z" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180); cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"></path></g><text dy=".35em" class="" transform="translate(77.74499355097029,51.88454845881587)" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none;">68.7%</text></g><g class="c3-chart-arc c3-target c3-target-FS2"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-FS2 c3-arcs c3-arcs-FS2"><path class=" c3-shape c3-shape c3-arc c3-arc-FS2" transform="" d="M-44.4439868873686,-108.0517735417486A116.83515625,116.83515625 0 0,1 -11.653578222643608,-116.25251760960121L0,0Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 140, 0); cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"></path></g><text dy=".35em" class="" transform="translate(-22.67752725334393,-90.67535579576993)" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none;"></text></g><g class="c3-chart-arc c3-target c3-target-Renewal"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Renewal c3-arcs c3-arcs-Renewal"><path class=" c3-shape c3-shape c3-arc c3-arc-Renewal" transform="" d="M-107.89143050974987,44.831829747643916A116.83515625,116.83515625 0 0,1 -44.4439868873686,-108.0517735417486L0,0Z" style="fill: rgb(0, 128, 0); cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"></path></g><text dy=".35em" class="" transform="translate(-86.32911494813567,-35.82700522353499)" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none;">25.1%</text></g><g class="c3-chart-arc c3-target c3-target-Tele-sales"><g class=" c3-shapes c3-shapes-Tele-sales c3-arcs c3-arcs-Tele-sales"><path class=" c3-shape c3-shape c3-arc c3-arc-Tele-sales" transform="" d="M-11.653578222643608,-116.25251760960121A116.83515625,116.83515625 0 0,1 8.230819442412569e-14,-116.83515625L0,0Z" style="fill: rgb(214, 39, 40); cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"></path></g><text dy=".35em" class="" transform="translate(-4.66725363658852,-93.35152454302703)" style="opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none;"></text></g></g><g class="c3-chart-texts"><g class="c3-chart-text c3-target c3-target-FS1" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-texts c3-texts-FS1"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-text c3-target c3-target-FS2" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-texts c3-texts-FS2"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-text c3-target c3-target-Renewal" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-texts c3-texts-Renewal"></g></g><g class="c3-chart-text c3-target c3-target-Tele-sales" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: none;"><g class=" c3-texts c3-texts-Tele-sales"></g></g></g></g><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-grid)" class="c3-grid c3-grid-lines"><g class="c3-xgrid-lines"></g><g class="c3-ygrid-lines"></g></g><g class="c3-axis c3-axis-x" clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-xaxis)" transform="translate(0,316)" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 0;"><text class="c3-axis-x-label" transform="" x="330" dx="-0.5em" dy="-0.5em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text><g class="tick" transform="translate(165, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"><line y2="6" x1="0" x2="0"></line><text y="9" x="0" transform="" style="text-anchor: middle; display: block;"><tspan x="0" dy=".71em" dx="0">0</tspan></text></g><path class="domain" d="M0,6V0H330V6"></path></g><g class="c3-axis c3-axis-y" clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-yaxis)" transform="translate(0,0)" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 0;"><text class="c3-axis-y-label" transform="rotate(-90)" x="0" dx="-0.5em" dy="1.2em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,296)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">0</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,257)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">10</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,218)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">20</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,179)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">30</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,140)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">40</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,101)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">50</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,62)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">60</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,23)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="-6"></line><text x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor: end;"><tspan x="-9" dy="3">70</tspan></text></g><path class="domain" d="M-6,1H0V316H-6"></path></g><g class="c3-axis c3-axis-y2" transform="translate(330,0)" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;"><text class="c3-axis-y2-label" transform="rotate(-90)" x="0" dx="-0.5em" dy="-0.5em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,316)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,285)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.1</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,253)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.2</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,222)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.3</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,190)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.4</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,159)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.5</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,127)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.6</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,96)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.7</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,64)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.8</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,33)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">0.9</tspan></text></g><g class="tick" transform="translate(0,1)" style="opacity: 1;"><line x2="6" y2="0"></line><text x="9" y="0" style="text-anchor: start;"><tspan x="9" dy="3">1</tspan></text></g><path class="domain" d="M6,1H0V316H6"></path></g></g><g transform="translate(0.5,320.5)" style="visibility: hidden;"><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-subchart)" class="c3-chart"><g class="c3-chart-bars"></g><g class="c3-chart-lines"></g></g><g clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip)" class="c3-brush" style="pointer-events: all; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><rect class="background" x="0" width="330" style="visibility: hidden; cursor: crosshair;"></rect><rect class="extent" x="0" width="0" style="cursor: move;"></rect><g class="resize e" transform="translate(0,0)" style="cursor: ew-resize; display: none;"><rect x="-3" width="6" height="6" style="visibility: hidden;"></rect></g><g class="resize w" transform="translate(0,0)" style="cursor: ew-resize; display: none;"><rect x="-3" width="6" height="6" style="visibility: hidden;"></rect></g></g><g class="c3-axis-x" transform="translate(0,0)" clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/charts/dashboard?operation=getUserDashBoard&amp;t=dashboardMenuOption#c3-1462852070590-clip-xaxis)" style="opacity: 0;"><g class="tick" transform="translate(165, 0)" style="opacity: 1;"><line y2="6" x1="0" x2="0"></line><text y="9" x="0" transform="" style="text-anchor: middle; display: block;"><tspan x="0" dy=".71em" dx="0">0</tspan></text></g><path class="domain" d="M0,6V0H330V6"></path></g></g><g transform="translate(258.2671875,0)"><g class=" c3-legend-item c3-legend-item-FS1" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer;"><text x="14" y="131" style="pointer-events: none;">FS1</text><rect class="c3-legend-item-event" x="0" y="117" width="43.296875" height="19" style="fill-opacity: 0;"></rect><rect class="c3-legend-item-tile" x="0" y="122" width="10" height="10" style="pointer-events: none; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></rect></g><g class=" c3-legend-item c3-legend-item-FS2" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"><text x="14" y="150" style="pointer-events: none;">FS2</text><rect class="c3-legend-item-event" x="0" y="136" width="43.296875" height="19" style="fill-opacity: 0;"></rect><rect class="c3-legend-item-tile" x="0" y="141" width="10" height="10" style="pointer-events: none; fill: darkorange;"></rect></g><g class=" c3-legend-item c3-legend-item-Renewal" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"><text x="14" y="169" style="pointer-events: none;">Renewal</text><rect class="c3-legend-item-event" x="0" y="155" width="68.25" height="19" style="fill-opacity: 0;"></rect><rect class="c3-legend-item-tile" x="0" y="160" width="10" height="10" style="pointer-events: none; fill: green;"></rect></g><g class=" c3-legend-item c3-legend-item-Tele-sales" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"><text x="14" y="188" style="pointer-events: none;">Tele sales</text><rect class="c3-legend-item-event" x="0" y="174" width="74.03125" height="19" style="fill-opacity: 0;"></rect><rect class="c3-legend-item-tile" x="0" y="179" width="10" height="10" style="pointer-events: none; fill: rgb(214, 39, 40);"></rect></g></g></svg>
```

There are many more such charts on a single html page.

Comment: `unable to convert svg` could you provide page and code samples to investigate?

Comment: @Vaviloff. Please see above, I updated the question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - placed that svg in empty html and it was successfully rendered with PhantomJS 2.1.1: http://i.imgur.com/58hdsLq.png Could you share the link to the full page? Could be issue with server.

Comment: Have you converted it into image? can you please share the code?

Comment: Cheers! Well, any luck trying my script from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's PhantomJS code that works for the SVG you provided (version 2.1.1).

```
var link = "http://example.com/svg.html";
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 720 };

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {

  var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }

  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));

};

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};

page.open(link, function(status) {

    console.log(status);

    // Give it time to load
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        page.render("svg.png");
        page.render("svg.pdf");
        phantom.exit(); 
    }, 3000);

});
```